# Can a custom console component modify standard pages?

Tags: console, custom-console-components, consoleintegrationtoolkit

Is it possible to use a custom console component to alter standard pages, much like the old ways of inserting javascript through home page components?

Answer (score 2):

You are likely to still have the same Cross Domain scripting issue as custom console components (Visualforce) are served from a different domain.  The Salesforce Best Practice would be to override the page with a complete Visualforce Page, depending on what type of "alteration" you are trying to accomplish.